# Die Bedeutung von "auf unseren Füßen gehen, nicht auf den Knien rutschen."

Tags: meaning

Aus dem [Spiegel Online](http://m.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/a-1014995.html#spRedirectedFrom=www&referrrer=https://www.google.com/) :

> "Von diesem Moment an gibt es eine Regierung", sagte Kammenos. Mit Blick auf die deutsche Politik sagte der Chef der Unabhängigen Griechen: **"Wir werden zu Merkel auf unseren Füßen gehen, nicht auf den Knien rutschen."**

Was bedeutet dieser Ausdruck?

> We're going to Merkel on our feet not on our knees

Comment: This appears to be a quote translated from Greek, likely it is a Greek proverb.

Comment: Are you sure Google translate would not have an answer for you here? Just enter "rutschen", and you should be able to extract the meaning of the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde  das so übersetzen:

*We're coming  to Merkel walking on our feet, not sliding on our knees.*

Ich hoffe, *sliding* ist korrekt für eine Person, die kniet und versucht, sich durch Bewegen der Knie weiterzubewegen.

Comment: *Crawling*, oder im Sinne des Ausspruchs vielleicht *begging* oder *groveling*.

Comment: We come upright on the same eye level, not crying for help on our knees.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to know the meaning instead of the exact translation. 
Going on feet is a symbol of pride and honor. That means, they see themselves at the same level/position. They are not going to kneel, like a slave.
 In German we would also say, they are on *Augenhöhe* which means, they all stand tall and no one is kneeling or doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Hier das Originalzitat:

> Μην μας περιμένουν όμως να πάμε γονατιστοί στη Μέρκελ. Θα πάμε όρθιοι, όπως πρέπει να πηγαίνουν οι Έλληνες.<sup>[ifmedia](http://www.ifmedia.gr/politics/32806-kammenos-emeis-tha-pame-opos-prepei.html)</sup>

Wörtlich übersetzt könnte man dies wie folgt ins Deutsche übertragen:

> Erwarten Sie nicht, dass wir auf Knien zu Merkel rutschen. Wir werden aufrecht zu ihr gehen, wie es sich für Griechen gehört.

Diese populistische Formulierung wurde sinngemäß wie folgt übersetzt:

> - Wir werden niemals als Bettler auf unseren Knien zu Merkel rutschen, wir werden aufrecht stehen, wie Griechen es tun.<sup>Spiegel</sup>
> - Wir werden zu Merkel auf unseren Füßen gehen, nicht auf den Knien rutschen. <sup>tz</sup>
> - We will never go as beggars on our knees to [German Chancellor Angela] Merkel, we will go standing tall as Greeks do. <sup>The Sydney Morning Herald</sup>

*Anmerkung:* Die Übersetzung von "όρθιοι" ist eben nicht "auf den Füßen", sondern "aufrecht" (*würdevoll*) als Gegenstück zu "auf den Knien" (*unterwürfig*). Die Spiegel-Übersetzung ist da irreführend.

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet das die Frage? Auch hier: Was bedeutet das denn nun?

Comment: @Em1 also, wer Deutsch, Englisch, oder Griechisch spricht, sollte die Aussage verstehen - das muss man doch nicht weiter erklären, oder? Andere Sprachen halte ich hier für nicht angebracht. Du kannst Dich aber gerne an einer ausschweifenden Erklärung versuchen, was Bettler und auf Knien rutschen angeht... wo ist Deine Antwort?

Comment: Anscheinend doch. Immerhin hat OP selbst schon eine (wenngleich nicht gute) Übersetzung ins Englische angeboten, die an für sich verständlicher ist, als die varianten von Spiegel und Co.

Comment: @Em1 ... Ich glaube, die Übersetzung des Morning Herald sollte doch alle Zweifel beseitigen, worum es hier geht, oder?